# TRIVIUM Stream cipher how it works

Tags: encryption, stream-cipher

Hello I am quite new in cryptography so I found Trivium stream cipher can anyone explain in basic language how Trivium cipher works

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/e2-trivium.html) then [this](https://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/p3ciphers/trivium/trivium_p3.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basics.**
In symmetric cryptography, encryption and decryption of a plaintext is done using the same key (unlike public-key cryptography). Trivium is a symmetric cipher and more specifically a stream cipher, meaning that a stream of random-looking (pseudorandom) bits is used for encryption/decryption (in contrast to a block ciphers where the plaintext is split into chunks). During the encryption phase the plaintext is XORed with the so-called *key stream / output stream* to give the ciphertext. Decryption is done analogously, i.e. the ciphertext is XORed with the key stream to give the original plaintext.

**NLFSR.**
A main building block of Trivium are so-called *nonlinear-feedback shift registers* (NLFSRs), which are extremely efficient to implement in hardware.
An NLFSR consist of an array of registers, where the size of the array is known as the *degree* of the NLFSR. Additionally, a feedback loop is specified by a set of boolean *feedback coefficients*.
The state of an NLFSR is updated in each "clock tick" by shifting the values in all the registers to the right and setting the new value of the left-most register equal to some *nonlinear* function of some subset of the current registers determined by the feedback coefficients. At each clock tick the NLFSR outputs the value of the right-most register. If the NLFSR has degree $n$, then the first $n$ bits of the output stream are exactly the initial state.

**Background.**
The Trivium stream cipher was selected as part of the portfolio of the eSTREAM project, a European effort completed in 2008 whose goal was to develop new stream ciphers. Its design was intended to have a simple description and a compact hardware description.

**Trivium.**
Trivium uses three coupled NLFSRs, call them $A$, $B$, and $C$, having degrees $93$, $84$, and $111$, respectively. The state of Trivium is simply the $288$ bits comprising the values in all the registers of the three NLFSRs. At each clock tick, the output of each NLFSR is XORed with the right-most register and one additional register; the output of Trivium is the XOR of the output bits of the three NLFSRs.
At each clock tick, the new value of the left-most register of each NLFSR is computed as a function of one of the registers in the same NLFSR and a subset of the registers from a second NLFSR.
Trivium uses an $80$-bit key and a $80$-bit *initialisation vector* (IV). The key is loaded into the $80$ left-most registers of $A$, and the IV is loaded into the $80$ left-most registers of $B$. The remaining registers are set to $0$, except for the three right registers of $C$, which are set to $1$. The NLFSRs are then run for $4\cdot 288$ clock ticks, (with the output discarded), and the resulting state is taken as the initial state. The cipher specification states that at most $2^{64}$ key stream bits can be generated from each key / IV pair.

**Reference**

Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell. 2021. *Introduction to Modern Cryptography, Second Edition* (3rd. ed.). Chapman & Hall/CRC.